# Axel-command-line-downloader just show progress?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

Is there any way to hide all output from axel command but DO NOT HIDE `progress bar`. I want to get output like;

```
[  5%] [0            1           2            3           ] [  567,5KB/s] [15:59]
```

This output from `axel -a` but it always print every step although I edited ~/.axelrc and /etc/axelrc I changed `# verbose = 1` with `0`
. I dont want to send it background like `command &`. Do you have any idea? Please dont suggest `wget` in wget I can do it with `-nv --show-progress` but no option for axel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `bash` terminal, you can use:

```
axel -a http://url | awk -W interactive '$0~/\[/{printf "%s'$'\r''", $0}'
```

With `-W interactive` awk reads line-buffered and writes unbuffered to stdout. Then `awk` searches for a `[` in the line and prints it with a `^M` character `$'\r'`.

You can also write a function for that:

```
function axel_progress {
  axel -a "$1" | awk -W interactive '$0~/\[/{printf "%s'$'\r''", $0}'
}
```

Now you can call `axel` by:

```
axel_progress http://url
```

Comment: not working from my end